# How much should I pay someone to stain my deck and fencing?

Tags: staining

Need to know how much for wooden fence and deck restaining? The color put on it a while ago is not a good color btw so pressure wash it good and re-stain with a dark brown color. How much should be charged for a handyman or fence company to do this, in Georgia. Inside & outside of fence 1000 SQ FT and deck is 400 SQ FT.

Comment: Too many variables - depends on size of deck, location (which you listed), how much prep work is required, type of wood, etc. Plus the exact same job by a handyman vs. fence company vs. contractor etc. will vary quite a bit. Most important for DIY SE, questions are preferred where the answer will have future use - service costs will change over time.

Comment: My fault, 1st post here. I edited it and it should now be more focused so as to help with the answering. I'm looking on other sites for a national average. It's a lot of work to pressure wash that many SQ ft of fencing and decking to remove  the other color. Don't want to charge to much but make a profit and still be an honest person since this is new to me. Charging so I can live.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you trying to find out how much **you** should charge someone else? ("make a profit", "Charging so I can live") or are you trying to find out what is a fair price for you to pay **someone else**? ("pay someone")?